# For death year, should I use N/A or --- if person still alive?

Tags: design, data, formatting

I am making an app that displays detailed information of all U.S. presidents. For each president, you can view data such as the year the president was born and died.

> #### George Washington
>
> President Number: 1
>   Born: 1732
>   Died: 1799
>   Party: Independent politician

What is the best way to indicate that there is no death year for presidents who are still alive? Should I write **N/A** or **---** or **—** after the **Died** label?

> #### Barak Obama
>
> President Number: 44
>   Born: 1961
>   Died: ???
>   Party: Democrat

Comment: I would try asking this question on http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Don't show it like that at all. Do it the way the reference books do it. Show it as 1732-1799 or 1961- depending on which is appropriate.

Comment: Makes me thing of the saying "live the dash" http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=live+the+dash

Comment: Have you considered the current date, followed by a question mark? ;-)

Comment: @Dronz That doesn't differentiate between unknown dates and still alive.

Comment: I was joking, not seriously suggesting it. Bad taste, bad idea. Sorry.

Comment: How about 1732-Pending... ? :)

Comment: @McGafter: "Pending". Funny!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Well, you can write the predicted year of death based on user research, or you can say "TBD" :).

And more seriously - it would be a good idea to develop two templates for this item, one for dead presidents and another one for those who are still alive. The "alive" one shouldn't contain the "Died" field at all.
The downside to this is that it may not be self-evident to the user that a president who was born in, say, 1924 and doesn't have a year of death listed is actually still alive, the user may think that the year of death is simply not listed. A good way to solve this would be to mention their age in either the Born or Died field respectively. So

> George H. W. Bush
>
> Born: 1924 (age 91)

but

> Ronald Reagan
>
> Born: 1911
>
> Died: 2004 (aged 93)

That's what Wikipedia does, at any rate.

Comment: I have noticed that Wikipedia does it this way, yet I don't like the inconsistency of only sometimes displaying the "Died" field.

Comment: @TotZam Note that wikipedia is extremly consistent in this: if the year of death is unknown, the field "Died" is still shown. This is a different information than that the person is still alive, and these two things have to be well distingished! Also, for living people, the parenthesis says "age", whereas for dead people it say "aged".

Comment: @TotZam. I'm actually with Vitaly on this. Providing N/A can be confusing, because it may be interpreted as ("We don't know"; "We haven't got these details yet"). I think the solution proposed is a good one, if truly concerned, you can always have "Died: still alive". This will make it as explicit as you can. But I'd refrain from using "N/A".

Comment: @Izhaki what about using a dash?

Comment: @TotZam Still not explicit as writing "Still alive".

Comment: @TotZam if the person was your (living but elderly) loved one would you be comfortable with the word "Died:" attached to their profile at all, with a big blank space just waiting to be filled in? What if they were terminally ill?

Comment: You can simply say "Lived: XXXX-YYYY (aged ZZ)" for deceased people, and "Lived: XXXX- (age ZZ)"; a simple dash is enough to suggest that they're still alive, as opposed to an unknown death: Lived: XXXX-???? (age ??). Still, I think the Wikipedia version is pretty decent.

Comment: @phyrfox Seems to me that this format could be interpreted as "Lived from 1900 till the age of 48".

Comment: @VitalyMijiritsky Your example is bad; written "Lived: 1900- (age 48)" would only make sense in the year 1948 or 1949. Since it's now 2015, no entry would read this way, short of a (major) typographical error. Anyone that interpreted this the wrong way has probably never used the Internet or probably shouldn't be using the resource being designed. I draw my UI examples roughly from IMDB, which lists TV series as either "XXXX-" to denote a current show, and "XXXX-YYYY" to denote a cancelled show. You'll also see this format on many resumes, bibliographies, etc.

Comment: @VitalyMijiritsky Also, look at headstones in a cemetery. People buy their headstones in advance. The headstone will read "FIRST MIDDLE LAST XXXX-" with an empty death year, to be filled in upon death. I see little reason to believe that just because the words aren't engraved in marble or stone that people would somehow lose their ability to reason.

Comment: @phyrfox I actually sort of like your idea, but at the same time, I'm sort of getting convinced that the wikipedia way is more correct.

Comment: @TotZam If you don't like the inconsistency of only sometimes displaying the "Died" field you might display both it and an "Age" field, and only one of the two will have a value. Personally though I like better this answer as-is, because having the "Died" field for a living person and leaving it empty might come across as bad taste in many contexts (would we like to see that when we read a page about ourselves?). It's a bit like writing "_not dead yet_", perfectly correct and yet potentially wrong in many ways (the same goes for "_Still alive_" of course).

Comment: Absolutely agree with the first option. While Wikipedia may be inconsistent, that is due to having different writers/editors, so this happens. A better example might be Ancestry.com, which presents data on individuals as your first example, age and no death date for living.

Comment: @EricStoltz Wikipedia is not inconsistent because there are different editors, the behavior is baked into the template system. Except for edge cases where people are not using templates for some reason, Wikipedia's behavior is always the same, just conditional on whether the person is alive or dead.

Comment: @SantiBailors My whole question was basically what to fill in if I have an empty "Died" field. Creating two fields that can be empty doubles this issue instead of solving it :)

Comment: @phyrfox - once the headstone is ready, you're all set - you just have that pesky **waiting** left.

Comment: Good answer; don't show what isn't there. Conversely, you could be explicit and say: "Died: not yet"; leaves no ambiguity.

Comment: @Mooz **Died: not yet** is extremely cynical, and also offensive, as explained in [a previous comment by SantiBailors](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/86756/for-death-year-should-i-use-n-a-or-if-person-still-alive#comment138588_86757)

Comment: Ok ok 50 upvotes have convinced me. Enjoy you 15 points :)

Answer (score 0):

Something I see a lot in books (I don't know where this is common, nor where your users are coming from) is to indicate the birth year with an asterisk (*) and the death year with some kind of cross, apparently called "dagger" according to Mac OS X's symbol selector (†). If you don't have either a birth or death year, you just list one year number with the appropriate symbol.

> George Washington (1732*-1799†)
>
> Barak Obama (1961*)
>
> Guillaume de Machault<sup>1</sup> (1337†)<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1: the first person I could think of of whom we don't know the birth year</sup>

Comment: How do you differentiate between date unknown and still alive?

Comment: Alice (543-?) for people whose date of death is unknown, but Alice (*1969) for people who are still alive.

Comment: I tend to use asterisks and dagger *before* the date, and skip them altogether when both dates are known.